# Read key value from array using document id (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Very new to flutter. I want to retrieve arrays of notifications using a specific document id and display [date, message, type] in my App. Tried to google but can't seem to find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this you will get specific document's data.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection('Customer').doc('paste-your-document-id').get();
```

you'll get whole data of `Notification` data then use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Whole Notification data will print.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Customer").doc(document_id).get().then((value) {
   Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = value.data();
   for(var element in map.values) {
     element.asMap().forEach((index, firebaseValue) {
       print(index);
       print('${firebaseValue['Date']}');
       print('${firebaseValue['Message']}');
       print('${firebaseValue['Type']}');
     });
   }
  }
);
```

Comment: I got error: A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

Comment: Tried to change it to the one below and it ran without issues. Just that nothing is printed.

FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Customer")
        .doc(GetStorage().read("docID"))
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      Map<String, dynamic>? map = value.data();
      for (var element in map!.values) {
        element.asMap().forEach((index, firebaseValue) {
          print(index);
          print('${firebaseValue['Date']}');
          print('${firebaseValue['Message']}');
          print('${firebaseValue['Type']}');
        });
      }
    });